# Reorg SYSIBM tables to reduce extents (XT) - change priqty & secQTY

Tags: db2, system-tables, system-databases, db2-zos

I have a new DB2 V12 database on z/OS 2.4 z13, with hundreds of programs to rebind, such as: sysibm.syspackage, sys.columns, sys.tables, etc. These will grow, hence the need to reorganize the tablespace for performance.

Maintenance window is one hour, so just one tables space is being done.

1. Is reorg run on system tables the same as for user tables?
2. Is there special IBEGENR (sp?) VSAM redefine needed for system tables.

Sample JCL:

```
   //REORGS1 EXEC PGM=DSNUTILB,PARM='MT03,REORG1DB' 
   //STEPLIB  DD  DSN=DSNC10.SDSNLOAD,DISP=SHR 
   //SYSREC   DD  DSN=&&SYSREC,DISP=(NEW,DELETE,DELETE),       
   //             SPACE=(TRK,(9000,5000),,,ROUND),UNIT=SYSDA 
 LISTDEF TBLSLIST                                     
     INCLUDE TABLESPACES DATABASE TR032             
 REORG                                                
    TABLESPACE LIST TBLSLIST   COPYDDN(CDD1) LOG NO  
    SHRLEVEL REFERENCE                               
    SORTKEYS SORTDATA SORTDEVT SYSDA                 
    STATISTICS TABLE(ALL) INDEX(ALL)
```

Comment: Thank you. The edited version does read better.
 I was ticked at first but new version has "The Elements of style"

Answer (score 0):

a hint / link for the special question
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=tablespace-reorganizing-catalog-directory
PS
db2 zos v12 utility guide is a pdf for download available. -----
searching for dsndb01 / dsndb06 (catalog DB) help's ----
the reorg/ rebuild index utility is the same as for user Tablespace